# D3 basic map outline is not showing up

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js

I am having some trouble getting a d3 outline map to show up on a local server. I have been looking on several local websites and have been running through several different tutorials and from what I have seen, this should be working. All I am seeing when I run the code is my navbar and a blank bootstrap container.  I have tried moving the code around, defining the svg variable within the d3.json function, although mostly I have been researching this issue trying to learn more about d3 and svg. I'm not sure if it's just a typo or something I'm doing wrong, Thank you for anyone who is able to assist!

My geojson is uploaded here:
https://github.com/cgirlamo/publicq

I got the translate and scale function from this tutorial:https://bl.ocks.org/d3indepth/3ccd770923a61f26f55156657e2f51e8

I know those won't get me exactly what I want in terms of a world map but at this point I am just trying to get something that shows up on my webpage.

The D3 version I am using is 3.3.13

```js
var width = 900;
var height = 600;

var projection = d3.geoMercator()
  .scale(400)
  .translate([200, 280])
  .center([0, 5]);

var path = d3.geoPath().projection(projection);
var svg = d3.select('body').append('svg')

var g = svg.append('g')

d3.json('countries.json', function (data) {


  g.attr('width',width)
  .attr('height',height)
  .selectAll('path')
  .data(data.features)
  .enter()
  .append('path')
  .attr('d',path);

});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

  <script src = 'JS_CSS_downloaded_libraries/bower_components/d3/d3.min.js'></script>
  <script src = 'JS_CSS_downloaded_libraries/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js'></script>
  <script src = 'JS_CSS_downloaded_libraries/bootstrap-3.4.1-dist/js/bootstrap.js'></script>
  
  <script src = "Mainjs.js"></script>
  <link rel = 'stylesheet' href = 'JS_CSS_downloaded_libraries/bootstrap-3.4.1-dist/css/bootstrap.min.css'>
</head>

<body data-spy = 'scroll' data-target="navbar">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li><a href="../../index.html">Home</a></li>

          <li class='active'><a href='../GEOG485L-WebMap/index.html'> My Web Map</a></li>
          <li class="dropdown">
            <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Whiskey
            <span class="caret"></span></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><a href="#">Standard</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Premium</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Ultra Premium</a></li>
            </ul>
            <li><a href ='#'>Wine</a></li>
            <li><a href = '#'>Beer</a></li>
            <li><a href = '#'>Spirits</a></li>

        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    </nav>

  <div class = 'container'>
    <div class = 'col-md-10'>
      
  <div id='mapid'></div>

  </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  



</body>
```

Comment: Few quick questions, which version of d3 are you using, can you share the geojson, and how did you determine the projection parameters (translate,scale,center)?

Comment: Hi @AndrewReid, I have updated the post with the answers to your questions, thank you for the quick response

Comment: Just on my hone, but your syntax is for d3 v4. Try that version, as your code looks otherwise ok, though you might see better results if you also remove the lines centering, translating, and scaling the projection.

Comment: That did it @AndrewReid thank you very much!